Android SDK Not Found error when try to build android, Old Cordova project
this is my very first time asking a question and asking for help in here.
I'm sorry if my lack of providing lack of information about the problem, i just got a new job as mobile dev, and i know zero to none using ionic,cordova. this is a old project my office never finish and hope that I can finish this project. but the problem is when i try to compile (i don't know the word) to apk using "ionic cordova build android" i have this =
Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

this is what i installed in my work laptop
ionic cli version 4.0.0 installed globally
cordova version 6.1.0 installed globally
latest android studio (koala currently)
gradle 8.1.0
SDK Platforms = android 8.0 ("Oreo")
SDK Tools = Build Tools Ver = 34.0.0 , 33.0.2 , 30.0.3
Java version 8
i don't know what else i should provide information, let me know if you need any other information
things I tried :
when running the app using "ionic serve" works but if i update ionic and/or cordova "ionic serve can't run again"
so i stuck with this version for now unless anyone have solution for this
set the enviroment variables correctly, if i try to run "echo %ANDROID_HOME%" in cmd it return the path correctly
set the path correctly
I expect to successfully compile and build the said project to APK
